# как выбрать данные из трех таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

вопрос заключается в следующем, есть три таблицы
первая user - с полями idu, fio

```
idu     fio
1      Петров
2      Сидоров
```

вторая карточка  - c полями idkart, status

```
id   status
1    2
2    5
```

третья объединяюшая kuist - idkuist, idkart, idu

```
idkuist  idkart    idu
1         1         2
2         2         1
```

надо выбрать всех пользователей (idu, fio) из таблицы user в ms sql server , idu которых нет в kuist и которые есть kuist, но у которых в карточке status не равен 2.

Comment: Ну так покажите требуемый ответ-то к показанным данным... и данные неплохо бы расширить, чтобы в них встречалась каждая из возможных комбинаций выполнения/невыполнения условий.

Comment: но ведь если пользователя нет в kuist то нет связи с карточкой, а значит нельзя проверить статус карточки?

Comment: @nörbörnën По-моему, ему надо "или вообще нет в kuist, или есть, но со статусом не 2"...

Comment: @Akina или kuist вообще не нужна

Comment: @nörbörnën `kuist` - таблица, без неё не достучаться до статуса персоны. Вот поле `idkuist` в ней действительно ниачём...

Comment: @nörbörnën kuist - таблица, связывающая user-а с карточками. если карточка относится только к одному пользователю то в kuist нет нужды

Comment: kuist объединяет не только эти три таблицы есть еще несколько полей, но не в этом суть, такой состав таблиц есть и изменить их не получится. Задача выбрать незарегистрированных пользователей - первое - это если пользователь заведен в систему но у него нет карточки (то есть его idu нет в kuist), и второе если у него есть карточка но статус не равен 2 (2 - действующая - idu есть в kuist - и если проверить idkart в таблице kart поле sost не равно 2)

Comment: тогда @Akina прав :) должно подойти что-то вроде `select * from user u left join kuist m on m.idu = u.idu left join kart k on m.idkart = k.idkart where m.idkuist is null or k.status <> 2`

Comment: Сделал так 'select DISTINCT u.IDU, u.Fam, u.Io, u.Dolzh, k.Sost INTO #Summary33 from asuusers.dbo.Users u 
left join asuusers.dbo.KUISt m on m.IDU = u.IDU 
left join asuusers.dbo.KartI k on m.IDKI = k.IDKI 
where  k.Sost = 2
ORDER BY Fam 

select DISTINCT * from asuusers.dbo.Users u 
left join #Summary33 m on m.IDU = u.IDU 
where m.IDU is null 
ORDER BY u.Fam'

Comment: только не пойму мне пишет в мс студио что В базе данных уже существует объект с именем #Summary33 и каждый раз надо менять имя временной таблицы???